# linkTo does not make full rows clickable

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use `linkTo` as explained [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2779)

This is my template:

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#linkTo "nodes.show" this tagName="tr"}}
        <td>{{shortenHash id}}</td>
        ...
        <td>
            <a {{action startEditing this bubbles=false}}><i class="icon-pencil"></i><a/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a {{action destroyRecord this bubbles=false}}><i class="icon-remove"></i><a/>
        </td>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

But this has several problems:

- the row is not clickable
- the `<a>` actions are clickable, but the cursor is not showing it

I am using the latest libraries:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:356
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.5 ember.js:356
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4 ember.js:356
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 ember.js:356
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:356
DEBUG: location=http://localhost:9001/#/nodes apiUrl=//localhost:8000 ember.js:356
DEBUG: SettingsApp.VERSION : 0.0.0 ember.js:356
DEBUG: EMBER_DATA_VERSION : Last commit: ed99201 (2013-06-18 04:39:18 -0700) ember.js:356
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:356
```

Answer (score 3):

`linkTo` by default generates an anchor '`A`' tag. This tag is not allowed to be directly attached to a `TABLE`, `TBODY` or `TR` element. See the '*Permitted Content*' section in the spec,

- [HTML5 TBODY](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html#tbody-content-model)
- [HTML5 TR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr-content-model)

What you probably want to do is attach a click event handler to the TR which is connected to an action that triggers the transition to '`nodes.show`'.

```
{{#each model}}
  <tr {{action "goToLink" model.id}}>
    <td>{{shortenHash id}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And controller,

```
var NodesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions : {
    goToLink : function(id) {
        this.transitionToRoute('nodes.show', id);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is maybe very opinionated, but bear with me.* If you have to render big lists where you end up doing pagination, you should rather take a different approach then using the old `table` markup. Here is where [`ember-list-view`](http://emberjs.com/list-view/) comes in. It's a ember addon that allows you to have long list but with very good performance. This is achieved by reusing DOM elements instead of creating all at once. The reason I propose this is because I've seen more people having this kind of issues using `{{linkTo}}` with `tagName="tr"`.

For more info on the `ember-list-view` please consider:

- [homepage](http://emberjs.com/list-view/)
- [github page](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view)
- [very detailed introductory talk by Eric Bryn @ebryn *(the creator)*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3vEjbjV8Sk)
- [demo](http://jsbin.com/omobov/1/edit)
- [download link](http://builds.emberjs.com/list-view/list-view-latest.js)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. It seems too complicated for me at the moment, so I will just renounce to having clickable rows. I'll consider that for a future implementation. Anyway, it would be interesting to know *why* `linkTo` is not working, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

For those Googling, Ember List View does not work with current stable Ember > 1.8
https://github.com/emberjs/list-view/issues/169

Maybe check out ember-cloak for something similar... https://github.com/eviltrout/ember-cloaking